# If The equation $ax^2+4xy+y^2+ax+3y+2=0$ represents a parabola then find the value of $a$.

Tags: conic-sections

*Problem*:If The equation $ax^2+4xy+y^2+ax+3y+2=0$ represents a parabola then find the value of $a$.

**My attempt**-I known that in a parabola($e=1$)[where $e$ is *eccentricity*].So the distance of any general point on any Conic from the directrix($ax+by+c=0$) must be equal to its distance from the focus($\alpha,\beta$).That means one can write the general equation of any conic in form of-
$$(x-\alpha)^2+(y-\beta)^2=e^2\frac{(ax+by+c)^2}{(a^2+b^2)}$$

This means that I have to *somehow* factorise the given equation in above form and then apply the necessary conditions for.But I haven't been able to get anything useful.

Can Anyone Help me a little bit with this? A Hint will also Suffice.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes#Elimination_of_the_xy_term_by_the_rotation_formula

Comment: There is an interesting fact: if $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$ is any nondegenerate conic, then it is a parabola if and only if $B^2-4AC=0$. This shows that your value $a$ must be equal to $4$.

Comment: @Crostul I was reading the same thing which you mentioned here from the Wikipedia link given by lab bhattacharjee But unfortunately I couldn't find its proof.Can you provide a link Where the result you mentioned is proved? Because I have encountered this formula for the first time And It just seems like magic to me.

Comment: Also should I delete the question because it turns out that by using the result mentioned by crostul .the question Becomes **Trivial**.And the answer is clearly $a=4$...so This question becomes same as asking what is $2+2$...and so  I don't think it will be of any help to anyone in the future.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no proof at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT :

Expand and simplify $$(A^2+B^2)((x-\alpha)^2+(y-\beta)^2)=(Ax+By+C)^2$$
to the form 
$$Dx^2+Exy+Fy^2+Gx+Hy+\color{red}{2}=0$$
Then, solve the following system : 
$$D=a,\quad E=4,\quad F=1.$$

Comment: @Freelancer : Take a look at [this site](http://www.wiley.com/college/anton/0471482749/appendices/app_h.pdf) which might enable you to prove the fact Crostul mentioned.